# Usage of While-do constructs LaTeX

Tags: conditionals, loops

I'm curious, when reading about the ifthen-packages I've come across the syntax of while-do statements. What are they used for ?

For example this piece of code from the documentation (this is copy-pasted):

```
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $sum\gets 0$
\State $i\gets 1$
\While{$i\le n$}
\State $sum\gets sum+i$
\State $i\gets i+1$
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
```

I know it loops until a specific condition is met. But what use does this have in a LaTeX-Document, that isn't running in real time like a program. I mean it compiles but there aren't any variables that change during compilation are there?

Comment: Are you aware of the `pgffor` package?

Comment: No I am not. I'm very new to LaTeX. Should I be looking into it ?

Comment: Well, it is up to you, but I believe the `\foreach` command comes rather close to what you want. It is documented on p. 901 ff of the pgfmanual. I personally learn most from examples. Perhaps you get a better answer if you detail an example where you want to use the while do stuff.

Comment: Actually I'm not trying to use it yet, for now I'm just trying to understand in what cases using said commands might be useful or lead to shorter, better style code.

Comment: OK, but after all this is a question. What kind of answer are expecting then?

Comment: Well maybe an example, an explanation to what it does. If this isn't the place for such things just let me know.

Comment: Normally you should present a real case example such that one can give a specific answer. Otherwise I cannot do more than telling you that `pgffor` may be useful, and of course there is a good chance that there is another package that comes even closer to what you want.

Comment: There seems to be a bit of confusion. LaTeX is used for typesetting, i.e., displaying content in a document. This content can be text, tables, images, graphs, etc, and also algorithms. For displaying an algorithm (i.e., a piece of text with programming statements in it) you can use the `algorithmicx` package, among other things. This does not in any way execute this code, it just displays the statements in a nicely formatted way. Now, apart from displaying code using LaTeX, you can also write code in LaTeX, and execute that, in order to automate the typesetting task to some extend. [...]

Comment: [...] For this internal LaTeX programming, you can use some native constructs like `if` and `repeat`, or packages like `ifthen` or `pgffor`. These allow you, for example, to print a line 10 times, or to create very complicated diagrams more easily. These two topics (displaying code in LaTeX and programming in LaTeX) are very different. Which one do you want to ask about?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. I edited the question, that it fits to what I was really trying to find out. So those things aren't used for running code. They just display it like for example listings ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, a possible use case is when you are writing a scientific paper about a particular algorithm and you want to display the pseudo-code of the algorithm to illustrate and clarify the text.